# Quali sono le differenze di uso dei verbi "profittare" e "approfittare"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Ho dei dubbi sull'uso dei verbi "profittare" e "approfittare". Non so se in alcuni contesti sono sinonimi o hanno invece diverse sfumature di significato o perfino usi totalmente differenti. Per fare un esempio, quale di queste due frasi sarebbe la corretta?

> - Cerco di *profittare* di quelle rare occasioni in cui si può ascoltare in diretta un'opera barocca qui a Barcellona.
> - Cerco di *approfittare* di quelle rare occasioni in cui si può ascoltare in diretta un'opera barocca qui a Barcellona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generalmente sinonimi nel senso di trarre beneficio  da qualcosa, approfittare è  spesso   usato in contesti negativi, come sinonimo di 'abusare'. Nelle due frasi riportate sopra, entrambi i verbi possono essere usati.

[Profittare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/profittare/): (Treccani.it)

Vocabolario on line
v. intr.  (aus. avere).

> - Fare profitto, avanzare, progredire: p. nello studio, nella carriera.
> - Trarre profitto, beneficio, vantaggio: ha profittato molto delle lezioni; mi sembra che profitti poco dei miei consigli.
> - Volgere a proprio vantaggio, usare a proprio beneficio, sfruttare: voglio p. dell’occasione; profitterò senz’altro del vostro invito; profittò della confusione per squagliarsela; con senso pegg., **abusare, servirsi di qualcuno: p. della buona fede altrui; si profitta di me; loro se ne profittano (in questi sign. è più com. approfittare).**

Comment: Non sono d'accordo con questa interpretazione. Per me profittare ha esclusivamente una connotazione negativa perché è strettamente connessa con la parola profitto. Mentre potrei dire ho approfittato questo fine settimana per mettere ordine in casa. Non necessariamente ha connotazione negativa.

Answer (score -1):

Assolutamente è corretto dire «*Cerco di *approfittare* di quelle rare occasioni in cui si può ascoltare in diretta un'opera barocca qui a Barcellona*», sebbene non possa escludersi che esistano *profittevoli* occasioni quali, in specie, quelle connesse ad un effettivo vantaggio immediato e materiale—alla cui categoria l'ascolto di opere barocche, in diretta o no, non appare sussumibile.

Comment: Manca la spiegazione della differenza tra i due verbi.

Comment: No, la spiegazione c'è, occorre solo comprenderla, @martina.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Una risposta non può essere un quiz.